# Can't inject content script into all IFRAMEs from my Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

In my Google Chrome Extension I need to be able to inject my *content script* into all `IFRAME`s on the page. To do this my original `manifest.json` was declared as such:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames" : true,
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],
```

This seemed to have worked for most sites, until I came across an `IFRAME` that was declared as such:

(From Chrome debugger)
[image]

and here's the HTML for it:

```
<iframe id="wysiwygtext_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area." style="width: 100%; height: 341px; display: block;"></iframe>
```

In this case my content script is not injected into that `IFRAME`.

I tried changing the `matches` filter to `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` but that still didn't do it.

Is there any way for me to inject my *content script* in an `IFRAME` like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly the problem that the `match_about_blank` flag was created for. It was finally released to stable in Chrome 37.

Just add `"match_about_blank": true` to the content script definition.

You can also use it in tabs.executeScript. See:

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts
- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-InjectDetails

Comment: Hey, you're the man! Thanks. I somehow overlooked the `match_about_blank` flag. I also ran into the `tabs.executeScript` solution but I couldn't find out how to use it to inject my content script when the page loads. Can you expand on that?

Comment: If you want to inject on every page load, you should just use the content script definition. To use tabs.executeScript you would generally use a background page that listens to tabs.onUpdated and calls tabs.executeScript on each page load.

Comment: OK what about the iframe he presented made it an "about:blank" iframe? Am I missing something?